# Some UILabels with one big text

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsstring, uilabel

I have one big NSString with a lot of symbols and I want to make some UILabels with it.
For example:
My text: I am from Moscow. My nickname is itruf.
Result:
First label: I am from Moscow.
Second label: My nickname is
Third label: itruf.

All UILabel must have one size and font (I want to make paging, like bookmate or ibooks).

PS: I want to make NSArray with my labels.

Comment: Is there a reason you want `UILabel`s and not something else?

Comment: You want to split the string? Take a look at `componentsSeparatedByString:`

Comment: I want to make some pages with UILabels, but if you have other ideas - it will be good.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *list = @"I am from Moscow. My nickname is itruf.";

NSArray *listItems = [list componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
myCity.text = [listItems objectAtIndex:0];
myName.text = [listItems objectAtIndex:1];
```

Where myCity and myName is your labels.

Comment: Да я не это имел ввиду. Там может не быть точек. Соль именно в объеме. Нужно что-то связанное с sizeWithFont и т.д. Чтобы UILabel с этим текстом был как раз по размеру моего view.

Answer (score 0):

Or if you want to adjust your label height,

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(20, 10, 190, 1000);
self.label.numberOfLines = 0;
self.label.frame = rect;
[self.label sizeToFit];
```

Then it'll automatically come down from 1000 to the reasonable height.

Comment: I want to make horizontal paging like book. For example: bookmate. I have custom class with two functions: numberofpages and contentforpageatindex:index. So I want to make NSArray with UILabels, and in function contentforpageatindex:index write this code: [myarray objectatindex:index];. So, I need to create some UILabels with rect equals my view rect and with same font.

Comment: OK, have you tried to do that in "for in" cycle?
Changing labels frame rect?

Comment: No, I haven't tried it. I've write code, which counting number of pages, but I haven't ideas to make labels. My code:` CGFloat cellWidth = 320.0f;`
    `CGSize textSize = [text sizeWithFont:descriptionView.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(cellWidth, FLT_MAX) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];`
 `NSUInteger number = textSize.height / self.view.bounds.size.height; `